# CSS not showing because for no apparent reason <head> is not appearing in _site folder

Tags: html, css, jekyll, head

My website was doing really good, but now for no apparent reason css is not showing up, due to the fact that `<head>` isn't appearing in _site folder. While at the same time it is obvious that my  is available in root directory.

Can someone help inspecting this? Because I am blind to the apparent bug.

**Link to website:** http://werkbaar.net/

**Link to repo:** https://github.com/bomengeduld/boilerplate

**Problem:**
When I do a chrome inspection on my website I notice that that  tags are stripped:

[image]

**Structure of indexpage:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    {% include head.html %}

    <!-- The #page-top ID is part of the scrolling feature - the data-spy and data-target are part of the built-in Bootstrap scrollspy function -->

    <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
        {% include nav.html %}
        {% include header.html %}

    {{ content }} 

        {% include footer.html %}
        {% include scripts.html %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the {% include head.html %} is importing the head.html from another place

Comment: Hi John, thanks for looking into this. Not sure what you want to suggest though. Everything seem obvious. I suggest you look at my github repo for more insight. head.html is in my _includes folder. Until now this was working smoothly. Why is it not working now?

Comment: the problem is not that head is hidden, but that head is empty... area you sure that "{% include head.html %}" points to the right file?

Comment: Nevermind, i found the bug. I forgot to add markdown YAML to my index.html. For some reason I erased it in a design process. My apologies for bothering. Thanks for your time John & Roberto.

Comment: TIP: You are allowed to answer your own question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding YAML front matter to `index.html` which links to my default.html where the `<head>` situated

```
---
layout: default
---
```